# Reference search not considering packages\package-name

Tags: c#, msbuild, azure-devops

I'm building a new pipeline in Azure DevOps and I am having an issue with one of the packages not being found (AWSSDK). Looking at the logs I can see that it is not searching in the obvious place which is D:\a\1\s\packages\AWSSDK.2.3.55.2\lib\net452\

See below the places where it is looking for the dll file. The rest of the logs after line 72 are about other C:\ places.

[image]

These logs are from an earlier build step which would restore the packages. Line 145 tells us that the package was added in the right place.
[image]

I am really not sure how to troubleshoot this, and also I am not sure if I can actually jump on the VM where this is build and investigate further.

Also here is an image with the steps of the agent.
[image]

Comment: Glad you got the solution. You can accept this answer. I think it would help other SO users who will facing the same issue :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more digging around, I found that in the csproj file the hint path for the reference was not set correctly. After I've changed it to the following, everything worked fine.

```
<Reference Include="AWSSDK, Version=2.3.55.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f476d3089b52be3, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>packages\AWSSDK.2.3.55.2\lib\net45\AWSSDK.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```